# How to concatenate Aliased Types (of consts) into strings.Join()

Tags: types, casting, go, alias

I have an package/API that allows for passing in a slice of values.  For example:

```
type ConstType string

const (
    T_Option1 ConstType = "OPTION-1"
    T_Option2 ConstType = "OPTION-2"
    T_Option3 ConstType = "OPTION-3"
)
```

Notice how this type is an alias of string.

**Where I am running into a what-i-think-is-non-idomatic-step is that I can't cast or infer a slice of this type alias to a `[]string` slice.**

```
type constTypes struct {
    types []ConstType
}

func (s *constTypes) SetConstTypes(types []ConstType) {
    s.types = types
}

func (s *constTypes) String() string {

    // this generates a compile error because []ConstType is not
    // and []string.
    //
    // but, as you can see, ConstType is of type string
    //
    return strings.Join(s.types, ",")
}
```

I put this together in the playground to show a complete example:

http://play.golang.org/p/QMZ9DR5TVR

I know the Go solution is to cast it to the type (explicit Type casting, love the rule!).  I just can't figure out how to cast a slice of types to []string - without looping through the collection.

One of the reasons I like Go is the enforcement of type casting, like:

```
c := T_OPTION1
v := string(c)
fmt.Println(v)
```

Play: http://play.golang.org/p/839Qp2jmIz

Though, I am unsure how to do this across the slice without looping.  Must I loop?

Given, looping through the collection is not a big deal since there will only be 5 to 7 options max set.  But still, I feel there should be a cast-able way to do this.

Comment: short answer - you can't cast a slace of a type to a slice of another type without looping through it.

Comment: Well, that's the answer I am looking for.  Post it to get it marked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Not_a_Golfer points out, you should really be looping through the slice of `constType` and building up a new slice of `string`. This has the disadvantage of copying each element (which may or may not matter to you).

There is another solution, although it involves the `unsafe` package from the standard library. I've modified the example that you posted to the Go Playground (new link is http://play.golang.org/p/aLmvSraktF)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "unsafe"
)

type ConstType string

const (
    T_Option1 ConstType = "OPTION-1"
    T_Option2 ConstType = "OPTION-2"
    T_Option3 ConstType = "OPTION-3"
)

// constTypes is an internal/private member handling
type constTypes struct {
    types []ConstType
}

func (s *constTypes) SetConstTypes(types []ConstType) {
    s.types = types
}

func (s *constTypes) String() string {

    // Convert s.types to a string slice.
    var stringTypes []string // Long varibale declaration style so that you can see the type of stringTypes.
    stringTypes = *(*[]string)(unsafe.Pointer(&s.types))

    // Now you can use the strings package.
    return strings.Join(stringTypes, ",")
}

func main() {

    types := constTypes{}

    // a public method on my package's api allows this to be set via a slice:
    types.SetConstTypes([]ConstType{T_Option1, T_Option2, T_Option3})

    fmt.Println(types.String())
}
```

Comment: Hah, unsafe! yeah, I was just seeing if I was missing something for casting. I see now, loop or unsafe it. Slight tweak to your code though: `fmt.Println(types.String())` to get the desired result.  Odd, I thought Println would call String(). +1

Comment: @PeterStace: NOTE: "Package unsafe contains operations that step around the type safety of Go programs. Packages that import unsafe may be non-portable and are not protected by the Go 1 compatibility guidelines."